# I can't update my data through $wpdb

Tags: php, database, mysql, wpdb

I am trying to update my sql data through $wpdb, but can't... If anyone can help what's the real issue?

```
$updated_version = $wpdb->update('wp_visitors', array('views' => $updated), array( '%d' ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing your where statement. You need to tell `wpdb` which row it should be updating, otherwise you're looking to insert rather than update.

[From the $wpdb::update Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/):

> ```
> wpdb->update( string $table, array $data, array $where, array|string $format = null, array|string $where_format = null );
> ```

Comment: What should I need to the where statement? I've got only 1 column so as the row.

Comment: `wp_visitors` only has the column `views`? If that's the case, you probably want to use something other than a custom table. Take a look at options, cache, or transients, depending on your needs.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand, and please let me know if there is any possible solution of it?

Comment: Your use of a custom table doesn't make sense.

Comment: All i want is to get a value to update the Visitor Counter.

Comment: Take a look at saving this as an option: https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API. You really don't want to hit the database with a write request for every visitor if you can help it, but if you're determined to do it this way, the options API will at least let you get and update a single value quickly. Using an entire custom table for this is overkill. Your question already highlights one of the reasons it's overkill. Best of luck.